# How to avoid concurrency exceptions when creating an XML-RPC service that needs to share global data across threads

Tags: java, web-services, concurrency, xml-rpc

I'm creating an XML-RPC server in Java using the [Redstone XML-RPC library](http://xmlrpc.sourceforge.net/). The server is responsible for kicking off commands on the system and then shooting back the response. For example, the user tells the server to do a `ls` and the server returns a listing of files. Similarly, the user can do asynchronous commands and get back a process ID to query with later. All these methods are under one big subclass of `Command` which is part of the main class `RPCServlet extends XmlRpcServlet`.

In order to accomplish this, I'm keeping a global HashMap of `instances`. When an async command comes in, I create an instance of class `ProcessManager` which extends thread. I then add it to the `instances` hash, run it, and return back the ID to the user. When a query for that ID comes in, I look it up in the global hash, and return either its full or partial status (depending on whether or not it's completed).

This works OK when it's just one request after another, but when you really begin to pound it with lots of requests that operate on the global hash `instances`, it gets concurrency exceptions.

Now here are my points of confusion:

- When a request comes in, does a new object of class `Command` get created or is it one object sitting there forever taking in commands? Following on that, how does each request see the global hash of `instances`? This is my init code

  public class RPCServlet extends XmlRpcServlet {

  ```
  @Override
  public void init(ServletConfig servletConfig) throws ServletException {
      super.init(servletConfig);  
      getXmlRpcServer().addInvocationHandler("Command", new Command(instances));  
  }
  ```

  }
- When I attempt to solve the concurrency exception issue, I use `syncronized` OR `ConcurrentHashMap` rather than `HashMap`. Either way, I run into deadlock this way. Why might this be?
- Where should my global HashMap of instances go? In `RPCServlet`? its subclass `Command`?

Here's how I run into these concurrency exceptions:

1. I create a bunch of async commands and then attempt to kill them all
2. I start lots of different clients all doing this, and it'll inevitably run into a concurrent exception.

Here is what the **asyncCmd** looks like:

```
public HashMap asyncCmd(XmlRpcStruct struct) throws XmlRpcFault {
            HashMap hash;
            if (struct.containsKey("command")) {
                ProcessManager proc = new ProcessManager(struct);
                boolean validInput = proc.readInHashValues();
                if (!validInput) {
                    throw new XmlRpcFault(400, proc.procResult.getTopError());
                }
                int id = proc.objectId;

                instances.put(id, proc);

                proc.start();
                String a;
                if ((a = proc.procResult.getTopError()) != null) {
                    throw new XmlRpcFault(500, a);
                }

                hash = new HashMap();
                hash.put("id", id);
                return hash;
            } else {
                throw new XmlRpcFault(400, "Unable to find a command");
            }
        }
```

**KillAll:**

```
public HashMap killAll() throws XmlRpcFault {
            HashMap retHash = new HashMap();

            int length = instances.values().size();
            if (length > 0) {
                Set keys = instances.keySet();
                for (Object key : keys) {
                    retHash.put(key, killAllKiller(Integer.parseInt(key.toString())));
                }
                //Since we killed all procs, suggest a GC as well
                instances.clear();
                System.gc();


                return retHash;
            } else {
                throw new XmlRpcFault(404, "No processes running");
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me suggest another alternative

- Upon receiving the request, put the command and an id into a [Queue](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/BlockingQueue.html) (wrap in an object), and return the id into the user
- Create a [ThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html) that will receive the commands from the queue, execute them and put the results in an [ConcurrentHashMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html)
- The clients will then access only the results map

In this way, there will not be a contention between new requests and results.

I would put this map in the servlet context, which the natural place to keep application level variables.

Comment: Thank you, that sounds much better. I'm going to go about implementing that now.